# How to use GUI in visual studio 2010 for android application

Tags: android, c++, visual-studio-2010

Hy I am new to visual studio .I search a lot and successfully create first application of android in visual studio 2010 using c++ but I don't find anything related to GUI.Please help me I want to create button,imageview,textbox etc in my android application using visual studio 2010 with c++

regards

Comment: I don't think Visual Studio has something like this. Why don't you try Java (it's easier and more modern and most Android applications are written in Java)? Anyway, try [this](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/cbuilder/create-android-apps).

Comment: I am using java before this But I am developing an android application which perform different operation on image using opencv so when i go for opencv I found more examples of opencv for c++ as compared to java

Comment: Why in the world would you *want* to do this? Android applications are written in Java. They *optionally* use native methods in *certain* rare situations.

Comment: @sheikh: This still means that most of the GUI should be written in Java.

Comment: Done with this can you please tell me how to use test  TessBaseAPI api.I am using this code but not getting desire result

 String path =  Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/OCRr/" ;
            tessBaseAPI.init(path,"eng"); 
            
           
      tessBaseAPI.setImage(imgbitmap);

            String text = tessBaseAPI.getUTF8Text();
            
            tessBaseAPI.end();

Answer (score 1):

To use native(C++) code in android application you need Android 
[NDK](https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html)

Comment: CAn you please help me to read text from image using tessrect  I doing this in eclipse
 String path =Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/OCRr/" ; tessBaseAPI.init(path,"eng"); tessBaseAPI.setImage(imgbitmap); String text = tessBaseAPI.getUTF8Text(); tessBaseAPI.end();

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to create a GUI for Android using C++ there several libraries to create layouts with few XML/Java lines? For your question I suggest you read the [Android NDK documentation](https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html#GetStarted) to know how to properly implement C++ in your project.

Comment: CAn you please help me I doing this in eclipse String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/OCRr/" ; tessBaseAPI.init(path,"eng"); tessBaseAPI.setImage(imgbitmap); String text = tessBaseAPI.getUTF8Text(); tessBaseAPI.end();